# The LIMIT clause in MySql doesn't seem to work with an IN() subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

Suppose, I have an SQL statement like the following.

```
SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country 
WHERE country_id 
IN(SELECT country_id FROM state 
   WHERE LENGTH(state_name)>=5 
   ORDER BY LENGTH(state_name) DESC);
```

It fetches all the countries from the `country` table whose corresponding state names in the `state` table are longer than 5 or more characters using a subquery as specified.

I want to retrieve only those countries whose corresponding **first 5 states** in the `state` table have 5 or more characters in length after sorting them in the descending order.

In this case, the `LIMIT` clause with the subquery doesn't seem to work and the following query fails to work.

```
SELECT country_id, country_name 
FROM country 
WHERE country_id 
IN(SELECT country_id FROM state 
  WHERE LENGTH(state_name)>=5 
  ORDER BY LENGTH(state_name) DESC 
  LIMIT 5);
```

The `LIMIT` clause used with the subquery causes the error specified as follows.

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

I'm using the MySql version 5.1.48

Is there a way to get around this situation?

Comment: The order by in the sub-select of the first query doesn't make sense (it doesn't make a difference for the `IN` operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to replace the `IN()` clause with an `INNER JOIN` against the same subquery.  As the error message says, `LIMIT` simply isn't supported in an `IN()` subquery.

```
SELECT 
  country.country_id, 
  country.country_name 
FROM
  country
  /* JOIN the main `country` table against a subquery that retrieves the limited country_id set */
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT country_id 
    FROM state 
    WHERE LENGTH(state_name)>=5 
    ORDER BY LENGTH(state_name) DESC 
    LIMIT 5
  ) subq ON country.country_id = subq.country_id
```

#### [Here is a demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3210a/2)

*(Yes, I know Canadians don't call them "States" and certainly GBR doesn't either)*

Comment: I think the OP may need to retrieve only a set of countries from the `country` table itself without using `inner join` so that the result set contains no duplicate countries but which appears to be irrelevant in this case.